# XSD - Validate unknown keys

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I need to validate something with the following format (an xml generated from an array). The thing is that the keys are random (`<key>6</key>`, `<key>14</key>`) so I can't make an `<element>` for it because it requires a name, that I don't have (since is random). Any idea how to do that?

```
     <Segments>
        <item>
           <key>6</key>
           <value>
              <ns1:Map>

              </ns1:Map>
           </value>
        </item>
        <item>
           <key>14</key>
           <value>
              <ns1:Map>

              </ns1:Map>
           </value>
        </item>
        ........
     </Segments>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, the element won't always be called "key", it could be something else? Then use a wildcard: xs:any.